# Interactive routing doesn't start in Altium (17 and 20)

Tags: altium

I have two ICs that I use them repetitively in my PCB designing. Recently, (Or Maybe I forget something), the Interactive routing doesn't start (it doesn't show the line from the pin)from some pins of my chip in Altium but it works fine when I start routing from the destination part to this pin. I need to know what my problem is.(the width and other rules seems are correct)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've forgotten to set Track-to-tack clearance before start routing in rules window.

```
(In PCB windows)Design->Rules
```

ِ [image]